# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report Version=10.5.3700.0 and VS2008 in my development PC and PC is 64bit.

When I run the application i am getting the below error.

The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.

I also changed the target platforms from Mixed to AnyCPU, but the issue is not yet resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing on a 64-bit machine, make sure the application properties under the Build tab have "Any CPU" as the platform target, and unselect the check box for "Prefer 32-bit" if you have the option. Crystal is very touchy about 32/64 bit assemblies, and makes some pretty counterintuitive assumptions which are very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I verified everything is in AnyCPU only.